# Error while handling constructors in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting the following error while running the following PHP code

```
class tableData
{
    private $row1 = array("Kalle1", "address1", "postal code1", "1@email.se", "070111001", "08111001");
    private $row2 = array("kalle2", "address2", "postcode2", "2@email.se", "070111002", "08111002");
    private $row3 = array("kalle3", "address3", "postcode3", "3@email.se", "070111003", "08111003");
    private $row4 = array("kalle4", "address4", "postcode4", "4@email.se", "070111004", "08111004");
    private $rader = array(array($row1),array($row2),array($row3),array($row4));
}
```

The error is corresponding to the variable `$rader`:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$row1' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_k.php on line 15

Can anyone help me correct this error?

Comment: Line 15 is the variable $rader in the above code.

Answer (score 2):

[The PHP manual states](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration [of class properties] may include an initialization,
>   but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be
>   able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

```
private $rader = array(array($row1),array($row2),array($row3),array($row4));
```

So your `$row1` is not a constant value, it requires run time information, ie the value that the variable holds.

When PHP is *compiling* your class, at the point of property initialisation, it has no idea what value your `$row1` variable holds.

You'll have to set that variable to empty or null (whatever suits), and either have a setter method which sets it and call that first, OR use a constructor if this is always going to be the same data.

Basically, you cannot set properties from values that would come later from the object at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a constructor to declare class variables that are populated with other variables.

```
class tableData
{
    private $row1 = array("Kalle1", "address1", "postal code1", "1@email.se", "070111001", "08111001");
    private $row2 = array("kalle2", "address2", "postcode2", "2@email.se", "070111002", "08111002");
    private $row3 = array("kalle3", "address3", "postcode3", "3@email.se", "070111003", "08111003");
    private $row4 = array("kalle4", "address4", "postcode4", "4@email.se", "070111004", "08111004");
    private $rader;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->rader = array(
            array($this->row1),
            array($this->row2),
            array($this->row3),
            array($this->row4)
        );
    }
```

}

This assumes you do intend to create a 3-level nested array.

Comment: You're missing `$this->` in `$row1` ...`